# R equivalent of case when in SQL?

Tags: sql, r, case, case-when

I have been using T-SQL for a while but I now have to make transition to R...

```
select case when date_column_1 < '20160801' then date_column_1 else '20160801' end as date_column_1, case when date_column_2 < '99991231' then '20190701' else date_column_2 end as date_column_2 from table
```

Also, apologies in advance with my crappy stackoverflow formatting skills.

Comment: `?pmin` for a parallel minimum sounds relevant `pmin('20160801', c('20160701','20160801','20160901'))` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one condition to check for each column, we can use `ifelse` here. If there are multiple conditions you could check `case_when` from `dplyr`.

```
transform(table, date_column_1 = ifelse(date_column_1 < as.Date('2016-08-01'), 
                                        date_column_1, as.Date('2016-08-01')), 
                 date_column_2 = ifelse(date_column_2 < as.Date('9999-12-31'),
                                        as.Date('2019-07-01'), date_column_2))
```

Assuming `date_column_1` and `date_column_2` are of Date class, you cannot directly compare dates with literal string (`"20160801"`) in R, so we convert the dates to compare to Date class as well. Moreover, for `date_column_2` do you mean to replace all values with the date `"2019-07-01"` ?

---

As mentioned by @G. Grothendieck `ifelse` would convert the dates to numeric. We can use `if_else` from `dplyr` which is type-strict and will maintain the dates.

```
library(dplyr)

table %>%
   mutate(date_column_1 = if_else(date_column_1 < as.Date('2016-08-01'), 
                            date_column_1, as.Date('2016-08-01')), 
          date_column_2 = if_else(date_column_2 < as.Date('9999-12-31'),
                            as.Date('2019-07-01'), date_column_2)))
```

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks. Updated the answer with `if_else`.